# convert NSNumber to BOOL objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to convert integers `0` and `1` to BOOLEAN  `YES` and `NO`

My code:

```
    NSNumber *num = 0;
    BOOL myBool = [num boolValue];
    NSLog(@"bool is: %@",myBool);
```

It gives output as `(null)`

What could be wrong?

Comment: You can not call a method on a null reference. `num` in this case is a null pointer.

Comment: @JacobRelkin I believe OP is thinking since `num` is set to `0`, the message `boolValue` should return `0` which is not the case here. What if it is `NsNumber *num = 1;` ?

Comment: Your code is right, it's just that you are logging a string-value variable (%@) you need to log a BOOL-value variable (%u)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, the initialization of your `NSNumber` is incorrect. You should use one of the `+numberWith:` class methods defined on `NSNumber`:

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithChar:(char)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedChar:(unsigned char)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithShort:(short)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedShort:(unsigned short)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithLong:(long)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedLong:(unsigned long)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithLongLong:(long long)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedLongLong:(unsigned long long)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithFloat:(float)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithDouble:(double)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithBool:(BOOL)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)value NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedInteger:(NSUInteger)value NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
```

`BOOL`s are just `signed char`s, so you cannot use the `%@` format specifier, but you can use any of the integral format specifiers such as `%d`, `%i` or `%c`.

However, to output `YES` or `NO`, you'd need to use a string:

```
NSLog(@"bool is: %@", (myBool) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: Update for modern Objective-C: you can use `@YES` or @NO` or `@42` or `@(someValue)` to convert to `NSNumber`!

Answer (score 6):

Given the incorrect assignment to `NSNumber` did you really mean to create an object containing an integer, or is your title question "convert int to BOOL" correct?

If the latter then to convert an `int` with the value `0` or `1` to `BOOL` you just cast:

```
int num = ...; // num is 0 or 1
BOOL myBool = (BOOL)num; // myBool is NO or YES
```

However a better conversion is:

```
BOOL myBool = num != 0; // myBool is NO for 0, YES for anything else
```

as this follows the Obj-C (and C) notion that zero is false and non-zero true.

If you wish to convert a `BOOL` value to the strings `"YES"` and `"NO"` then this simple function will do it efficiently:

```
NS_INLINE NSString *BoolToStr(BOOL b) { return b ? @"YES" : @"NO"; }
```

just place it in a convenient header and import wherever you need it.

Answer (score 4):

To Covert `Int` to `BOOL`

convert an int with the value 0 or 1 to BOOL you just cast

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; // num is 0 or 1
BOOL myBool = [num boolValue];  // myBool is NO or YES
```

Answer (score 3):

As sch mentioned you messed it up right here:

```
NSNumber *num = 0;
```

- asterisk is a pointer/reference to an object ( a block of memory in your RAM ).
  It can hold just the memory address value ( no integers/bools ) of memory block for your object.
  Even in Objective-C don't mistake BOOL, int, float, double, NSInteger numeric types with objects (NSNumber).

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true about pointers. As an optimisation in Mac OS X, `NSNumber` instances are implemented as tagged pointers, meaning that the actual number is stored in the pointer itself (if it can fit) and a few remaining bits are used to "tag" the pointer (make it distinguishable from actual pointers) so that the runtime can just shift the tag bits out.

Answer (score 1):

as point it out by @jacob Relkin. you are wrong in use of `NSNumber`.

secondly, `boolValue` can convert `NSString` and `NSNumber` -> `BOOL`. `boolValue` works :

> Skips initial space characters (whitespaceSet), or optional -/+ sign
>   followed by zeroes. Returns YES on encountering one of "Y", "y", "T",
>   "t", or a digit **1-9**. It ignores any trailing characters.

for `int` you could use it as `boolean`

> BOOL a = num;  //will behave just like boolValue.

Answer (score 1):

i do not know if im completely right about this but when you assign a NSNumber as '0' you're giving the value 'nil' if you want the number you should go for '@0' or '@1' or use the method "numberwithint"